# Why git 0.01 doesn't have git-add?

Tags: git

I'm interested in the original version of git. The earliest version I can find is git v0.01 in [kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/). After compiling I get 7 executable file: init-db, read-tree, write-tree, commit-tree, show-diff, update-cache, cat-file.

```
./init-db
```

is similar to git init.  It creates a dir named.dircache. But I can find the corresponding command of

```
git add test.c
```

How does git 0.01 add files?

Comment: I assume that there was no notion of "index" or "repository" back then, but without actually reading significant portions of the source, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha there is an "index" file in .dircache. The source code seems very simple. wc *.c *h tells that there are only 1076 lines.

Comment: Surely out of those seven, it can't be anything else but update-cache that adds files to the cache (aka index)?

Comment: Do we even know for sure the add functionality was there? Could it be tracking all files in the current working directory and automatically adding them to the change list?

Comment: @YasserElsayed I think there is. otherwise commit-tree would be useless

Answer (score 2):

use update-cache to add file

```
./update-cache cat-file.c README

./show-diff
README: ok
cat-file.c: ok
```